# want to replace my old 3 way light switch

Tags: lighting, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

I bought slide dimmer FEIT and want to replace my old stairs basement light switch, however I am not getting how the current wiring is done

I am attaching the current diagram ( I am bad in diagrams )

[image: basement lighting]

new switch ( slide dimmer) has 4 wires : 1 black 2 red and 1 green

I assume my current setup has not a ground ?

A1 and B2 are always hot
A3 and B1 are hot only when then light is on
A2 and B3 noting even light is on or off

so my question :

is the wiring should be like this

- A1 ( 2 black) to Black dimmer
- A2 ( white) to Red dimmer
- A3 (black) to Red dimmer
- B2 ( white ) to Black dimmer
- B1 ( red ) to Red dimmer
- B3 ( black) to Red dimmer

the green dimmer wire will be left unplugged

Thanks in advance

Comment: Green or bare wires are the _safety_ ground. They should always be connected to the in-wall ground wiring or the grounding screw in the box (if it's a metal box) if at all possible. It may not be necessary to make the switch work properly, but it's an added safety feature.

Comment: Can you identify the 3-way travelers?  If the 3-way group is working, travelers will be on the **brass** screws not the black or green.  There will always be 2 travelers, one hot, one not, and they exchange if a certain 3-way switch is thrown

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch boxes please?

Comment: Many electronic switches need a true electrical ground they actually return a very small current to the electrical system without a proper ground if the switch is not working this is the reason.